# Listview when reaching bottom of list after filtering the list app crashes

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-filter

I i'm currently trying to implement a Listview that dynamically changes when users enters a search query or when an option is selected from the filter options. I have the search function working but the filter options are not.
By filter options i mean if the user taps on an option from the popup list shown below.
[image: Filter Popup menu]
 The problem is if i press a filter option the list does get filter and is displayed correctly but when i try and scroll to the button of the list the app will crash. I'm getting an IndexOutOfBoundsExecption but i cannot figure out why. The full error from logcat is

```
    01-16 19:26:11.126 9933-9933/uk.ac.uea.campus_map E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: uk.ac.uea.campus_map, PID: 9933
                                                                    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 29, Size: 29
                                                                        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                        at kyle.frameworklibrary.Rev.List.getItem(List.java:37)
                                                                        at kyle.frameworklibrary.Rev.InfoItemListController.getItem(InfoItemListController.java:25)
                                                                        at kyle.frameworklibrary.Rev.InfoItemListController.getView(InfoItemListController.java:47)
                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2376)
                                                                        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1972)
                                                                        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
                                                                        at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:668)
                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5221)
                                                                        at android.widget.ListView.trackMotionScroll(ListView.java:1889)
                                                                        at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4769)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:616)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6209)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
01-16 19:26:11.126 9933-9933/uk.ac.uea.campus_map D/AppTracker: App Event: crash
01-16 19:26:11.139 9933-9933/uk.ac.uea.campus_map I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9933 SIG: 9
```

My ListView class code is

```
        package uk.ac.uea.campus_map;

    import kyle.frameworklibrary.Rev.InfoItem;
    import kyle.frameworklibrary.Rev.InfoView;
    import kyle.frameworklibrary.Rev.ListController;
    import kyle.frameworklibrary.Rev.ListView;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.app.SearchManager;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
    import android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu;
    import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    /**
     * Created by Danny on 14/01/2017.
     */

    public class BuildingListView extends ListView implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
        AppContainerActivity callback;
        BuildingListController listController;
        SearchView searchView;

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
            callback.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.building_list_toolbar, menu);
            searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.search));
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) callback.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(callback.getComponentName()));
            searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        }

        public static Fragment createFragment(AppContainerActivity ACA){
            BuildingListView thisListView = new BuildingListView();
            thisListView.setACA(ACA);
            return thisListView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public void setACA(AppContainerActivity ACA){
            callback = ACA;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(int i) {
            InfoView goToFrag = new InfoView();
            goToFrag.setInfo((InfoItem)lc.getItem(i));
            callback.gotoFragAdd(goToFrag,0,0);
        }

        @Override
        public ListController getListController() {
            listController = new BuildingListController(callback.buildingList, this);
            return listController;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            lc.getFilter().filter(newText);
            lv.setAdapter(listController);
            lv.invalidateViews();
            return false;
        }




        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.filter_academic_dept:
                    lc.getFilter().filter("type_academic_dept");
                    lv.invalidateViews();
                    lv.refreshDrawableState();
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

and my listadapter code is

```
package uk.ac.uea.campus_map;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Filter;
import kyle.frameworklibrary.Rev.InfoItem;
import kyle.frameworklibrary.Rev.InfoItemListController;
import kyle.frameworklibrary.Rev.List;
import kyle.frameworklibrary.Rev.ListView;

/**
 * Created by Danny on 16/01/2017.
 */

public class BuildingListController extends InfoItemListController {
    protected  ItemFilter itemFilter;

    public BuildingListController(List<InfoItem> l, ListView li) {
        super(l, li);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if(itemFilter == null){
            itemFilter = new ItemFilter();
        }
        return itemFilter;
    }


    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String filterString = constraint.toString();
            FilterResults fitlerResults = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint!=null){
                List<InfoItem> tempList = new List<InfoItem>();

                if(filterString.startsWith("type")){
                    filterString = filterString.substring(5);
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.getSize(); i++) {
                        if (list.getItem(i).getType().toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                            tempList.add(list.getItem(i));
                        }
                    }
                } else  {
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.getSize(); i++) {
                        if (list.getItem(i).getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(filterString)) {
                            tempList.add(list.getItem(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
                fitlerResults.count = tempList.getSize();

                fitlerResults.values = tempList;
            }

            return fitlerResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            filteredList = (List<InfoItem>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }




}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You should most probably override getCount method in your BuildingListView and return amount of items you have after filtering